# How to disable change in a line in Excel but still be able to use the filter/sort arrow

Tags: excel, vba

I found online many VBA scripts that disable a certain range of cell to be editable but I'm always facing the same issue : I need the first line (containing columns names) to be uneditable but I still want the user to have the possibility to click in the bottom right corner arrow of the cell to be able to sort the data or to filter it.

Is it doable or the moment we disable change in a cell the filter arrow is not exploitable ?

I've tried to disable change in a range of cells with different VBA codes and locking a certain range using format cells protection but both ways when the cells is blocked for editing I can't use the arrow in the cell.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't been clear sorry, Line 1 contains columns name, I don't want the user to be able change the column name or to delete one but I still need the user to be able the small arrow on the bottom right corner to filter the data, to sort it... is it doable ?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Could you describe in more detail and post the codes (change, protect)?

Comment: Then, you must use `ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True`. Of course, instead of `ActiveSheet` you may use any sheet object...

Comment: First thing I did, Ctrl A in the entire file, right click -- format cell -- protection -- untick Locked Cells. Then same procedure for the first line only and I ticked Locked Cells. Then I protected the sheet and only ticked 'Select Unlocked Cells'. I have now the first line protected and the other ones editable but I can't use the edit/filter arrow in the cells of the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make Header Row Unselectable

- The following needs to be copied into the sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`) of the worksheet where it needs to be applied.
- There's nothing to run, it runs automatically.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' You may need to adapt this to your requirements.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Me.UsedRange.Rows(1)
    'Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Me.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange
    
    If Not Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            On Error Resume Next
                Target.Offset(1).Select
            On Error GoTo 0
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```